# Is it possible to inherit required options in argparse subparsers?

Tags: python-3.x, argparse

I am trying to write a command line application that has several modes in which it can run (similar to `git` having `clone`, `pull`, etc.). Each of my subcommands have their own options, but I also wanted them to share a set of required options, so I tried using a parent parser to implement this. However, it seems that inheriting a required option is causing the subparser to keep asking for it. Here is an example recreating the behavior:

```
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The parent parser")

parent_parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, required=True,
                           help="set the parent required parameter")

subparsers = parent_parser.add_subparsers(title="actions", required=True, dest='command')
parser_command1 = subparsers.add_parser("command1", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The command1 parser",
                                      help="Do command1")
parser_command1.add_argument("--option1", help="Run with option1")

parser_command2 = subparsers.add_parser("command2", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      add_help=False,
                                      description="The command2 parser",
                                      help="Do command2")

args = parent_parser.parse_args()
```

So now if I run `python test.py` I get:

```
usage: test.py [-h] -p P {command1,command2} ...
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: -p, command
```

Ok, so far so good. Then if I try to specify just the `-p` option with `python test.py -p 3` I get:

```
usage: test.py [-h] -p P {command1,command2} ...
test.py: error: the following arguments are required: command
```

But then if I run `python test.py -p 3 command1`
I get:

```
usage: test.py command1 [-h] -p P [--option1 OPTION1] {command1,command2} ...
test.py command1: error: the following arguments are required: -p, command
```

If I add another `-p 3` it still asks to specify `command` again, and then if I add that again it asks for another `-p 3` etc.

If I don't make the `-p` option required the problem is fixed, but is there a way to share required options among multiple subparsers without just copy pasting them within each subparser? Or am I going about this entirely the wrong way?

Comment: You have told `parent_parser` and `parser_command1` to both require a '-p' argument.  So you have to `test.py -p 1 command1 -p 2`, etc.  Each level meets its own requirements.  You could still use `parent_parser` to populate the subparsers, but define a separate `main_parser` that does not require `-p'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the main parser and parent parser functionality:

```
import argparse

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="The parent parser", add_help=False)

parent_parser.add_argument("-p", type=int, required=True,
                           help="set the parent required parameter")


main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="actions", required=True, dest='command')
parser_command1 = subparsers.add_parser("command1", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      description="The command1 parser",
                                      help="Do command1")
parser_command1.add_argument("--option1", help="Run with option1")

parser_command2 = subparsers.add_parser("command2", parents=[parent_parser],
                                      description="The command2 parser",
                                      help="Do command2")

args = main_parser.parse_args()
```

The main parser and subparser both write to the same `args` namespace.  If both define a 'p' argument, the subparser's value (or default) will overwrite any value set by the main.  So it's possible to use the same 'dest' in both, but it is generally not a good idea.  And each parser has to meet its own 'required' specifications.  There's no 'sharing'.

The `parents` mechanism copies arguments from the parent to the child.  So it saves typing or copy-n-paste, but little else.  It's most useful when the parent is defined elsewhere and imported.  Actually it copies by reference, which sometimes raises problems.  In general it isn't a good idea to run both the parent and child.  Use a 'dummy' parent.